# Updating array of objects with arrayFilters

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-update

I am trying to update an array of objects by applying a filter but no updates happen on any of the objects and no errors appear. I would like all objects according to my filter to be updated. I am using MongoDB version 6.0.8.

Query:

```
Buildings.update({}, {
  $inc: { "floors.$[index]": -1 }
}, {
  arrayFilters: [ { "index": { $gt: 2 } } ]
});
```

Data:

```
{
  _id: "YuzMQ5zKgktzrANsq",
  floors: [
    { index: 0 },
    { index: 1 },
    { index: 2 },
    { index: 3 },
    { index: 4 },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `arrayFilters` and `$set` operator were incorrect. Since you are trying to update the field in the object, you need the [dot notation with `$[<identifier>]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-documents-that-match-arrayfilters-in-an-array).

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $inc: {
    "floors.$[i].index": -1
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "i.index": {
        $gt: 2
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7djaqbExYFP)